# Mvvmcross MvxNavigationService issue when await result

Tags: xamarin, navigation, mvvmcross

I, I have an issue with the last mvvmcross version, with xamarin.forms.

If I await the result of a second viewmodel, when that second viewmodel, await again for another navigation, the first navigation returns with a null Tresult.

That is wrong because the first navigation in the first viewmodel should wait until the second viewmodel is explicitly closed.

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue with double awaiting when expecting a TResult. You can follow it here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3184. I think you should change one of the await navigation for a Message or try to do the navigation differently or see if you can workaround the situation somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MvxNavigationViewModel instead of MvxViewModel your view model parent class